# Transactional replication of Date column from Sql Server 2012 SP4 to Azure Sql Database

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-database, azure

We have a Sql Server 2012 SP4 where we are trying to setup transactional replication to Azure Sql Database. When starting replication is says

> Column *mycolumn* in object *mytable* contains type Date, which is not supported in the target server version, SQL Server 2005.

Since Azure Sql Database should support Date datatype [Data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the problem could be that Sql Server identifies Azure Sql Database as version 2005.

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: what is your db compatiblity level ? Run `SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'YOURDBName'`  and then you can use `ALTER DATABASE [YOURDBName] SET compatibility_level  = 110` -- 2012 version.

Comment: The compatibility level was 90. I'll see if we can change that without breaking any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*converting my comment to answer ...*

Since you confirmed that the db compatiblity is 90 which is sql 2005

Run

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'YOURDBName'
```

and then you can use `ALTER DATABASE [YOURDBName] SET compatibility_level = 110 -- 2012 version`

Comment: I can verify that changing the compatibility level to 110 got things working and the replication in now running.